# PHP: как достать атрибут из XML-файла при помощи SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
$xmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="2015-11-30 10:01">
 <shop>  
  <offers>
   <offer id="10933" available="true">    
    <params>
     <param name="Пол"><![CDATA[Для женщин]]></param>
     <param name="Тип изделия"><![CDATA[Платье]]></param>
     <param name="Основной цвет"><![CDATA[Фиолетовый]]></param>
     <param name="Материал"><![CDATA[Хлопок]]></param>
    </params>
    <sizes>
     <size id="18394"><![CDATA[S (36-eu, 42-ru)]]></size>
     <size id="18395"><![CDATA[M (38-eu, 44-ru)]]></size>
    </sizes>  
   </offer>
  </offers>
 </shop>
</yml_catalog>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//shop/offers');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($nodes);
```

результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [offer] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10933
                            [available] => true
                        )

                    [params] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [param] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Для женщин
                                    [1] => Платье
                                    [2] => Фиолетовый
                                    [3] => Хлопок
                                )    
                        )

                    [sizes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [size] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => S (36-eu, 42-ru)
                                    [1] => M (38-eu, 44-ru)
                                )    
                        )    
                )    
        )
```

)

Подкажите как и атрибут достать или вернуть обьект в виде

```
 [param] => Array(
      [пол] => Для женщин
      [тип изделия] => Платье
      [Основной цвет] => Фиолетовый
      [Материал] => Хлопок
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, по умолчанию у функций `simplexml_load_file()` и `simplexml_load_string()` нет возможности подставлять атрибуты в качестве ключей. Однако, это можно сделать искусственно, после того, как XML-файл распаршен. Для этого нужно просто добавить недостающие элементы при помощи метода `addChild()`.

```
<?php
$xmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="2015-11-30 10:01">
 <shop>
  <offers>
   <offer id="10933" available="true">
    <params>
     <param name="Пол"><![CDATA[Для женщин]]></param>
     <param name="Тип изделия"><![CDATA[Платье]]></param>
     <param name="Основной цвет"><![CDATA[Фиолетовый]]></param>
     <param name="Материал"><![CDATA[Хлопок]]></param>
    </params>
    <sizes>
     <size id="18394"><![CDATA[S (36-eu, 42-ru)]]></size>
     <size id="18395"><![CDATA[M (38-eu, 44-ru)]]></size>
    </sizes>
   </offer>
  </offers>
 </shop>
</yml_catalog>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//shop/offers');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  foreach($node->offer->params->param as $key => $value) {
    $node->offer->params->addChild($value['name'], $value);
  }
  foreach($node->offer->sizes->size as $key => $value) {
    $node->offer->sizes->addChild($value['id'], $value);
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($nodes);
```

В результате будет получена следующая структура

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [offer] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10933
                            [available] => true
                        )
                    [params] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [param] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Для женщин
                                    [1] => Платье
                                    [2] => Фиолетовый
                                    [3] => Хлопок
                                )
                            [Пол] => Для женщин
                            [Тип изделия] => Платье
                            [Основной цвет] => Фиолетовый
                            [Материал] => Хлопок
                        )
                    [sizes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [size] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => S (36-eu, 42-ru)
                                    [1] => M (38-eu, 44-ru)
                                )
                            [18394] => S (36-eu, 42-ru)
                            [18395] => M (38-eu, 44-ru)
                        )
                )
        )
)
```